# Error when using speech-to-text model downloaded from Tensorflow Hub

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I want to implement speech recognition on Android to continuously listent and detect the keywords. I came across TensorFlow library and it looks like ideal option because it is easy to use, offline and I can use already prepared models.

I downloaded this example https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/android/tutorials/audio_classification and run it in Android Studio without any problem. But it uses a small model (in TFLite format) including only couple of words. Because of this I downloaded this model https://tfhub.dev/neso613/lite-model/ASR_TFLite/pre_trained_models/English/1 in the same format but when I replace the file in the project and run it, I get the following error:

```
Input tensor 396 to op 14 (RESHAPE) is not produced
Error getting native address of native library: task_audio_jni
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred when initializing AudioClassifier: Could not build model from the provided pre-loaded flatbuffer: Input tensor 396 to op 14 (RESHAPE) is not produced
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier.initJniWithModelFdAndOptions(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier.access$000(AudioClassifier.java:74)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier$1.createHandle(AudioClassifier.java:143)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier$1.createHandle(AudioClassifier.java:136)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils$1.createHandle(TaskJniUtils.java:70)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:91)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromFdAndOptions(TaskJniUtils.java:66)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.audio.classifier.AudioClassifier.createFromFileAndOptions(AudioClassifier.java:134)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.audio.AudioClassificationHelper.initClassifier(AudioClassificationHelper.kt:80)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.audio.fragments.AudioFragment$onViewCreated$1.onCheckedChanged(AudioFragment.kt:99)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:200)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:62)
    at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:385)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:221)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:137)
    at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:77)
    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:142)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

I use virtual device (Pixel 6 with android 11.0 (R)) in Android Studio.

Could anyone help me to get the speech recognition to work? No matter if I use this model or download another from the TensorFlow Hub.

There is a note on the model website:

`You can use this to convert the pre-trained models to TFLite Format.`

But the model is already converted to TFLite so I don't know if there should be another conversion to be done and how it should be done. There is some breif description about the conversion but it's python and I don't understand it. Since this example is official, I expected more info to be available about troubleshooting.

Comment: Task audio classifier is using model created by the model maker with applying metadata. You have to see the documentation what models are supported and create one from scratch with model maker in order the task Audioclassifier to support it. Otherwise you have to go with TensorFlow Lite interpeter and custom code based on inputs and outputs